# Share operator that doesn't unsubscribe

Tags: rxjs

I need to lazy load some infinite streams because they are expensive to start. And I also don't ever want to stop them once they are started for the same reason.

I'm thinking it would be neat if there was a [share](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share) operator that didn't unsubscribe from the underlying stream ever once it is subscribed for the first time, even when all downstream subscribers unsubscribe.

Right now I'm doing it with a publish and a connect on two different lines, which works alright but just seems clunky and not very rxjs like:

```
public data$(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.lazyData$) {
        return this.lazyData$;
    }

    this.lazyData$ = this.someDataProvider.data$()
    .publishReplay(1);

    this.lazyData$.connect();

    return this.lazyData$;
}
```

Also I want it to replay the last message to new subscribers as you see :)

Comment: The current implementation of `shareReplay` effects the behaviour you are after. It unsubscribes only when/if the source completes. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2910

Comment: Oh there we go, that worked thanks :) And thanks for the link too. I had to update to rxjs 5.5.5, but otherwise it just worked. You should put that as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `shareReplay` operator was added in RxJS [version 5.4.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#540-2017-05-09). And, in [version 5.5.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#550-beta4-2017-10-06) a [bug was fixed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2910) so that it maintains its history when its subscriber count drops to zero.

With the fix, `shareReplay` will effect the behaviour you are looking for, as it will now unsubscribe from the source only when the source completes or errors. When the number of subscribers to the shared observable drops to zero, the shared observable will remain subscribed to the source.

---

The behaviour of `shareReplay` has changed several times and a summary of the changes - and the reasons for them - can be found in [this blog post](https://ncjamieson.com/whats-changed-with-sharereplay/).

Answer (score 1):

[As of RxJS 6.4.0, you can specify shareReplay refCount behavior.](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay#reference-counting)

```js
source.pipe(
   shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
)
```

shareReplay will unsubscribe from source after all subscribers have unsubscribed.